# Pod install overwrote my modified pod library. How to revert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

Ok so I modified one of my cocoa pod's imported files and then I had to do a pod install, not realizing that would overwrite my changes to my existing cocoa pod files. How can I revert to my previous changes?

Comment: not possible? unless you have time machine backup

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't have a time machine backup, but Macs have a feature where they auto-save files regularly so that you can go back in time and view the file's history. I opened the file in TextEdit, went to File -> Revert To -> Browse All Versions and restored the correct version.